# Value of variables in NSCollectionViewItem is incorrect or nil

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I have a `NSCollectionView` in my `NSViewController` and I pass the data as follow:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        guard let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("ExploreMainCollectionItem"), for: indexPath) as? ExploreMainCollectionItem else { fatalError() }
        
        item.categoryName.stringValue = exploreData.exploreCategories[indexPath.item].name
        item.exploreCategoryIndex = indexPath.item
        
        return item
    }
```

In the `NSCollectionViewItem`, I have another `NSCollectionView`. When I try to use the data passed from previous VC, it is not what I passed and always the default value.

[image]

I tried reloading the collectionview inside a `didSet` on the `exploreCategoryIndex` and it has changed values but when it goes to the collectionview methods, it is always the default value of `exploreCategoryIndex`.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.